# gulp is not calling the callback -- it just hangs at end of task

Tags: node.js, gulp

`callback` is firing, but task just hangs on `Finished 'hooks:pull' after 2.04 s`

```
gulp.task('hooks:pull', function(callback){
  var files = [
    { remote: '~/deploy/test.example.com/hooks/post-receive', local: './bin/post-receive.test' },
    { remote: '~/deploy/staging.example.com/hooks/post-receive', local: './bin/post-receive.staging' },
    { remote: '~/deploy/example.com/hooks/post-receive', local: './bin/post-receive.production' }
  ];

  async.each(files, function(file, cb) {
    var opts = {
      host: 'example.com'
    };

    opts.file = file.remote;
    opts.path = file.local;

    scp.get(opts, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return cb(err);
      }

      console.log('%s hook has been pulled!', file.local);
      cb();
    });
  }, function(err){
    if ( err ) {
      console.error(err);
      return callback(err);
    }

    callback();
  });
});
```

How do I get it to call the callback and exit/return?

Just running `gulp hooks:pull`

Comment: Not enough info, can't reproduce.

Comment: @Heikki i updated with real example

Comment: Are you running `gulp hooks:pull` or some other task when this happens?

Comment: Just running `gulp hooks:pull`

Comment: What is your gulp version? Does it still hang if you replace `scp` part for example with `setTimeout(cb, 1000);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem (PEBKAC)

I had this line at the top of the `gulpfile.js` which was causing it to hang.

`var app = require('./server/index');`

Not sure why I added that, but removing it fixed it.

Comment: Uh, that's not a PEBKAC. That's a bug: requiring a file should not create a task which you need to (somehow) terminate before you can exit cleanly.

Answer (score 6):

If node hangs instead of exiting, presumably a task is still running.

You can use the Gulp `stop` hook to kill it, or just to exit the whole thing if you don't care (and if you don't start any async cleanup functions in your tasks).

This should do it:

```
process = require("process");
gulp.on('stop', function() { process.exit(0); }
```

Comment: *Sigh*. This solution does work. Yes, it is a quick and dirty hack, which is all it ever was intended to be. Please don't downvote without explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (?) with this setup:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var async = require('async');
var scp = require('scp');

gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    var files = [
        { remote: '.gitconfig', local: './foo' },
        { remote: '.gitconfig', local: './bar' },
        { remote: '.gitconfig', local: './baz' }
    ];
    async.each(files, function(file, cb) {
        scp.get({ host: 'localhost', file: file.remote, path: file.local }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return cb(err);
            }
            console.log('%s has been pulled!', file.local);
            cb();
        });
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return callback(err);
        }
        callback();
    });
});
```

.. which is practically the same except host & files.

Comment: It just hangs for me.

Comment: I even tried your exact example with localhost and it still hangs for me.

Comment: Are the files copied though?