# gulp and promises aren't getting resolved

Tags: node.js, gulp

This example is from the docs, but the task itself does not exit when running from the command line. It runs and finishes, but does NOT return to the shell like every other gulp task I use.

```
var Q = require('q');

gulp.task('somename', function() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  // do async stuff
  setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve();
  }, 1);

  return deferred.promise;
});
```

How do I get this task to exit back to the shell? I realize I can explicitly called `process.exit(0)` but this breaks the chainability.

Comment: Is this the entirety of your gulpfile? What is the exact command you are running in your shell?

Comment: Probably the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708608/gulp-is-not-calling-the-callback-it-just-hangs-at-end-of-task

Answer (score 2):

Works for me, again :)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var Q = require('q');

gulp.task('somename', function(callback) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 1);
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Results:

```
∴ gulp somename
[13:35:51] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/promise-test/gulpfile.js
[13:35:51] Starting 'somename'...
[13:35:51] Finished 'somename' after 1.69 ms
∴
```

Versions:

```
∴ node -v
v0.10.33
∴ npm -v
2.1.5
∴ gulp -v
[13:37:34] CLI version 3.8.9
[13:37:34] Local version 3.8.9
```

Comment: I agree. Maybe because of that it's not accepted. I'd still think it is valuable to show that the problem might be different that question states.

Comment: Weird, this does exit by itself. I must have some other thing going on that is blocking it from exiting.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you dont have a callback in your function but the "Works for me" answer does. When I removed the callback from my function, it did not exit automatically, replicating your problem.

Add a callback... ie:

```
var Q = require('q');

gulp.task('somename', function(callback) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  // do async stuff
  setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve();
  }, 1);

  return deferred.promise;
});
```